# Monitor screen randomly goes blank while using Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, screen, hardware, monitor, input

I have a weird problem. When I am on Ubuntu, screen randomly goes blank and comes back while I am moving the mouse or pressing keys on keyboard. Monitor connections, cables are all fine.

The same thing doesn't happen on the bios screen. I am dual booting Windows and there is no problem on Windows too.

I don't want to pass this off by saying my Ubuntu installation is just corrupted because this started happening after I opened the side panel of my PC case just to look at it for other reasons.

I am worried I might have damaged some hardware due to static electricity but I have some questions. If I damaged something, why is it only happening on Ubuntu while Windows is perfectly fine? If I didn't damage anything, why did this problem start after I opened the side panel of my case?